# Count the appearance of a string and the belonging result in the rows above

Tags: r, pattern-matching, sax, string-matching, sliding-window

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(value = c("a","b","b","d","a","b","b","d","a","b","c","d"), 
             pattern = c("NA","a","ab","abb","bbd","bda","dab","abb","bbd","bda","dab","abc"))
```

The value column indicates the actual behaviour, and the pattern shows the cummulative behaviour before this action happens. 
Now I want to compare the patterns with the 4 patterns above and count the number of appearances, plus the number of appearance of the belonging letter in the "value"-column, to calculate the expected result.

The result should look like this:

```
   value pattern apperance a b c d exp.result
1      a      NA      0    0 0 0 0       <NA>
2      b       a      0    0 0 0 0       <NA>
3      b      ab      0    0 0 0 0       <NA>
4      d     abb      0    0 0 0 0       <NA>
5      a     bbd      0    0 0 0 0       <NA>
6      b     bda      0    0 0 0 0       <NA>
7      b     dab      0    0 0 0 0       <NA>
8      d     abb      1    0 0 0 1         d
9      a     bbd      1    1 0 0 0         a
10     b     bda      1    0 1 0 0         b
11     c     dab      1    0 1 0 0         b
12     d     abc      0    0 0 0 0       <NA>
```

I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's me but I can't fully understand what you're asking... can you make some descriptive examples, e.g. "on row 9, appearance should be 1 because bbd occurs one time in pattern column of the previous rows..." etc

Comment: @digEmAll sure thing. You already got it right. 
For example: On row 11 is the pattern "dab", which already occurs 4 rows above on row 7. The value on row 7 is "b", that's why the expected result is "b". But if the same pattern occurs 5 rows above only, the appearance is 0, because of the sliding window of 4 rows.
Hope that helps.
I also want to add, that on my real data set, I have more than 400 rows and want to create a sliding window of 60 rows at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this approach :

```
df <- data.frame(
        value = c("a","b","b","d","a","b","b","d","a","b","c","d"), 
        pattern = c(NA,"a","ab","abb","bbd","bda","dab","abb","bbd","bda","dab","abc"))

win <- 4
analyzeWindow <- function(idx){
  idxs <- max(1,idx-win):(idx-1)
  if(idx == 1) idxs <- integer()
  winDF <- df[idxs,]
  winDF <- winDF[na.omit(winDF$pattern == df$pattern[idx]),]
  expValWeights <- unlist(as.list(table(winDF$value)))

  c(appearances=nrow(winDF),expValWeights)
}

newCols <- t(sapply(1:nrow(df),analyzeWindow))
df2 <- cbind(df,newCols)
df2$exp.result <- colnames(newCols)[-1][max.col(newCols[,-1],ties.method='first')]
df2$exp.result[rowSums(newCols[,-1]) == 0] <- NA

> df2

   value pattern appearances a b c d exp.result
1      a    <NA>           0 0 0 0 0       <NA>
2      b       a           0 0 0 0 0       <NA>
3      b      ab           0 0 0 0 0       <NA>
4      d     abb           0 0 0 0 0       <NA>
5      a     bbd           0 0 0 0 0       <NA>
6      b     bda           0 0 0 0 0       <NA>
7      b     dab           0 0 0 0 0       <NA>
8      d     abb           1 0 0 0 1          d
9      a     bbd           1 1 0 0 0          a
10     b     bda           1 0 1 0 0          b
11     c     dab           1 0 1 0 0          b
12     d     abc           0 0 0 0 0       <NA>
```

NOTE:
This code requires the "value" column being of type factor. Use `as.factor` if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The function `rollapply` from the package `zoo` may be helpful.

Define your original data.frame and load package:

```
library(zoo) 
df <- data.frame(value = c("a","b","b","d","a","b",
                           "b","d","a","b","c","d"), 
                 pattern = c("NA","a","ab","abb","bbd","bda",
                             "dab","abb","bbd","bda","dab","abc"))
```

Define a function that will spit out the number of times the fifth element appears in the first four:

```
f <- function(x) sum(x[5] == x[1:4])
```

Apply this function using `rollapply`:

```
df$appearance <- rollapply(df$pattern, 5, f, align = 'right', fill = NA)
```

I'm not sure if I'm interpreting your letter columns right, but you could use the same (or similar) function for the individual letters and then split the resulting column into 4 based on the value column.

```
df$letters <- rollapply(df$value, 5, f, align = 'right', fill = NA)
df$a <- 0
df$a[df$value == 'a'] <- df$letters[df$value == 'a']
```

It's up to you how to handle the NA values at the start.

If I may take a guess, it looks like you are working with DNA codons. In the off chance you haven't done so already, you may want to take a look at existing packages. Bioconductor in particular has a number of useful ones for working with biological data.